# OneDrive FilePicker cannot set filter with uppercase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onedrive, filepicker

I'm currently working on a project that is using the [OneDrive filepicker v7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/js-v72/open-file?view=odsp-graph-online)

I would like to limit the file selection by setting a filter when open up the filepicker. The file extension that I would like to set is .ttf, .TTF. However, when it is applied, it cannot filter by the uppercase extension.

How can I achieve to filter with uppercase?

```
var odOptions = {
   clientId: "INSERT-APP-ID-HERE",
   action: "query",
   multiSelect: false,
   advanced: {
      queryParameters: "select=id,name,size,file,folder,photo,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl",
      filter: ".ttf,.TTF" 
   }
}
```

[image: onedrivefile]

Comment: It seems like you have a small typo in your code. In your filter option, you've written .bpm,.BMP. that's why you are not getting uppercase. Update it to .BPM

Comment: It seems like you have a small typo in your code. In your filter option, you've written .bpm,.BMP. that's why you are not getting uppercase. Update it to .BPM

Comment: Hi, sorry, it is my typo here. I'm looking for TTF file only actually. I tried with '.ttf' or '.TTF' or '.ttf,.TTF', however, it will only look for file with small case. i updated my case on top, with the screenshot.